# Finding products from multiple categories in Prestashop 1.7.6.8

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm migrating a working module from ThirtyBees to Prestashop 1.7.6.8 - the purpose of the module is to display selected categories on Manufacturer pages.
The problem is, I cannot seem to get the grasp of the new SearchQuery mechanism. It seems like a great upgrade but ....

I can specify 1 category by using:
$query->setIdCategory($category_id);
Query being of type ProductSearchQuery

Is there an example somewhere on how to combine Queries?
(In the working module, I just do a id_category IN (2,4,6) for instance

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( We “fixed” it by adding categories matching our manufacturers - also allowing us to use facets on the manufacturer pages. Made a small override that redirects the manufacturer page to the corresponding category page